# Expect a type error, .pch file isn't working

Tags: ios, xcode

I have:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

in my .pch file, but it is not being called for my .mm file.

All my "expected a type" errors go away when I have `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` in the .mm file.

Does .mm not trigger `#ifdef _cplusplus`?

Comment: why not just put your "`#include`" at the top of your .mm file?

Comment: I'm going to have the include in every .mm file, figured it was better form.

Comment: a .pch file is not a .mm file, which is why "`#ifdef _cplusplus`" isn't being called.  Could you do the "`#include`" without the "`#ifdef`" in the .pch file?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand the question. The .pch file is tacked onto every .h and .m file. Thus, if "#ifdef _cplusplus" is passed, the "#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>" is called.

Comment: The issue was fixed by setting the value of Compile Sources As to Objective-C++.